# Plot with a different scale

Tags: r, plot

I have question about how to plot a figure with differnt axis scale, the pseudo-code is like:

```
plot(data1,data2,xlim=c(0,10,100,1000),ylim=c(0,1000))
```

that means the interval of x-axis is not even, but with different scale.

Thanks Dwin! You gave me another way to plot.
what I want to plot is like this figure, do you know how to plot it?  [image]

Comment: Not a proper problem description. `xlim` and `ylim` can only have length=2 vectors. Are you asking how to construct log scale for the x-axis? If so, then look at ?plot.default and the log="x" argument.

Answer (score 3):

```
options(scipen=8); plot(10^(1:5),1:5, log="x")
```

It is a common question what to do about the location of 0 on the log scale but try typing `log(0)` at the console to see why it will not appear.

Comment: Awesome! it's exactly I want! Thanks again!